# device not responding to productsRequest:didReceiveResponse:

Tags: objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase, itunes

why device is not responding to method:

```
 - (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
```

while simulator is responding? What i Google is to hard reset all device setting etc but couldn't get luck. Application is rejected from app store previously And again i added the products fresh and clicked on ready to upload binary. Status of products is 'waiting for review', is it enough for sandbox testing? and status of application is 'waiting for upload'.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it my own. My device is working on WiFi network which might be slow or having bandwidths that are distributed. I turn on mac WiFi, create network, start sharing the internet services in system preferences under network. I made my iPod to join network that i create on my mac machine, delete and rebuild the application and everything works like charm. Its recommended to reset all the setting in device if anyone get this type of problem